# Behaviour change with *ngFor

Tags: angular

I use Ionic to display some cards from data in firebase.

In some cards, I need to call a javascript function `divs2applet()`.
This function come from a module extern which displays draughts’s game.
I put it in the `ngOnInit()` of my `home.ts`.
But we can guess that call of `divs2applet()` is not correct because, the data are display in text.

When I use this without `*ngFor`, it works ...

Here is my `index.html` where I integrate script of this module :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ionic App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps (remove if not needed) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->
  <link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/themes/jquery.contextMenu.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--<link href='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/themes/hv.jquery.view.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->

  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/js/ui/jquery.easing.1.3_min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/js/ui/jquery.contextMenu_min_2.3.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/js/dcoerterp_view-2.3.8.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>
  <script src='http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/js/dambord.js' type='text/javascript'> </script>


  <script type='text/javascript'>
  function getOptions(appletID)
    {
      var opties = {
          showNotation:false, //montrer la notation près du plateau
          showGameList:false, //si plusieurs parties PDN, une boîte de sélection montrant dessus du plateau
          showSlider:false, //montrer un curseur de la progresssion de la partie sous le plateau
          showContextMenu:true, //Droit sur la carte ne montre pas ou un menu d'options
          showLastMove:false, // Dernier mouvement joué affiché sous le plateau
          closable:false, //L'applet peut être fermé avec X dans le coin supérieur droit
          squareSize: 27, //grootte van 1 speelveld (indirect bepaald dit de grootte van de totale applet
          themeURL: 'http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/applet/oerterpapplet2.0/themes/pieceimages/', //emplacement où sont les images et le fond
          liveMode:true, //betreft het weergave van partijen die worden ingevoerd via electronische borden of ipads.
          liveRefreshSec: 5,
          playMode:false, //default afspeelmode
          analyseMode:false, //en mode d'analyse, vous pouvez vous mettre à jouer
          isTB:false, //L'applet est affichée via la base tournoi
          borderSize: 15, //épaisseur du bord du plateau
          borderAllAround:false, //plateau bordure sur les côtés de la carte, ou seulement au-dessus et à gauche
          gotoPly:0, //open de stand na zet x, ply 1 is bijv de eerste zet, ply 2 is de eerste witte en zwarte zet.
          m_showNotation : false, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu peuvent activer ou désactiver l'utilisateur zetnotatie
          m_showNotationPDN : true, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: mode d'écran au format PDN ou désactiver
          m_showSourcePDN: true, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu de l'écran, l'utilisateur peut «chargé PDN dans applet' ou désactiver
          m_showPhotos : false, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker de spelerfotos aan- of uitzetten
          m_showLastMove : true, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker de laatse zet tonen, aan- of uitzetten
          m_showSlider : false, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: l'utilisateur peut activer ou désactiver le curseur de la partie
          m_showFieldNumbers:false, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: l'utilisateur peut activer ou désactiver le numéro de champ des champs
          m_showTurnBoard : false, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: l'utilisateur peut exécuter l'aide par le menu
          m_takeScreenshot : true, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker een screenshot maken van de stand
          m_enableMoveAnimation : true, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker kiezen voor simpele vorm van schuiven van de schijven (wel of geen animatie)
          m_playVariations : false, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker kiezen om alle varianten in de PDN af te spelen of over te slaan 
          m_startAnalyzeMode : false, //menuopties tonen in menu: kan gebruiker een analyse bord openen vanuit de applet
          m_restoreBoardLocation : false, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: L'utilisateur peut définir l'applet à sa place initiale et la taille après avoir traîné 
          m_showFEN : true, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu: l'utilisateur peut interroger la FEN de la position actuelle du conseil
          m_loadPDN : true, //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu peut charger l'utilisateur PDN dans l'applet
          m_help : true //Afficher les options de menu dans le menu, l'utilisateur peut consulter l'aide

      }

      var appletDiv = $('#' + appletID);

      if (appletDiv.attr('applet_playerimages') && appletDiv.attr('applet_playerimages') == 'true') opties.showPlayerPhotos = true;
      if (appletDiv.attr('applet_full_border') && appletDiv.attr('applet_full_border') == 'true') opties.borderAllAround = true;
      if (appletDiv.attr('applet_square_size')) opties.squareSize = parseInt(appletDiv.attr('applet_square_size'), 10);
      return opties;
    }
  $(function() {
    divs2applet();
  });
  </script>

<link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
       It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
  <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

my home.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


declare var divs2applet;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
   items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list('article');
       this.items = this.itemsRef.valueChanges();
       this.items.subscribe(res=> console.log(res));
  }


 ngOnInit(){
    divs2applet();
  }

  navigate(id: string){
    console.log('testetstest')
    console.log('id :', id);
    this.navCtrl.push('ArticlePage',{id:id});
  };
}
```

my `home.html` who displays a game :

```
 <ion-content class="cards-bg">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (items | async)?.slice().reverse()" text-wrap>
      <ion-card *ngIf="item.type === 1" tappable (click)="navigate(item.id)" class="cards-bg">
        <img src="assets/imgs/chpt2017.jpeg"/>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                {{item.titre}}
            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                {{item.titre2}}
            </p>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>

     <ion-card *ngIf="item.type === 2" class="cards-bg">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                {{item.titre}}
            </ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-content>
        <div class='applet'>
          [Event "Nationale Clubcompetitie KNDB 2013/2014"]
           [Site ""]
           [White "Quentin"]
           [Black "Mélanie"]
           [Result "0-2"]
           [GameType "20"]
           [Round "8"]
           [Date "2014.01.11"]
           [WhiteTime ""]
           [BlackTime ""]
           [WhiteUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/opvraag/liddetailp.php?SpId=1069"]
           [BlackUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/opvraag/liddetailp.php?SpId=3073"]
           [WhitePhotoUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/Afbeeldingen/Spelers/1069.jpg"]
           [BlackPhotoUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/Afbeeldingen/Spelers/3073.jpg"]
           [WhiteFlagUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/Clublogos/CEMA - De Vaste Zet Geleen.gif"]
           [BlackFlagUrl "http://toernooibase.kndb.nl/Clublogos/WSDV Wageningen.gif"]
           [WhiteRating "1026"]
           [BlackRating "3208"] 
           1. 34-30 20-25 2. 31-27 25x34 3. 39x30 17-21 4. 44-39 21-26 5. 50-44 11-17 6. 30-25 19-24 7. 27-21 16x27 8. 32x21 14-20 9. 25x14 10x19 10. 21-16 5-10 11. 37-31 26x37 12. 41x32 6-11 13. 40-34 10-14 14. 44-40 18-23 15. 34-29 23x34 16. 40x20 15x24 17. 49-44 12-18 18. 47-41 8-12 19. 41-37 4-10 20. 46-41 10-15 21. 44-40 18-23 22. 32-28 23x32 23. 37x28 12-18 24. 39-34 7-12 25. 16x7 2x11 26. 41-37 14-20 27. 37-32 1-7 28. 42-37 9-14 29. 37-31 3-9 30. 34-29 20-25 31. 29x20 15x24 32. 43-39 11-16 33. 31-26 18-22 34. 32-27 22x31 35. 36x27 24-29 36. 33x24 19x30 37. 35x24 16-21 38. 27x16 7-11 39. 16x18 13x35 40. 24-20 25-30 41. 20-15 30-34 42. 38-33 9-13 43. 48-42 13-19 44. 42-37 19-24 45. 33-28 35-40 46. 26-21 17x26 47. 28-22 40-44
          </div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

That’s what should be displayed :
[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07BOX.png)

But I have that :
[not works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fs3X.png)

I don’t understand why the call in ngOnInit() doesn't work in this case.
For information, I'm newbie.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you imported divs2applet() in the component?

Comment: I don't know if I did that :D
How to do that ?
But if I write just <div class=applet>.....</div> without *ngFor, I have no problem.
I think div2applet() is not call at the good moment since I loop on data from firebase.